# Requirejs Optimizer with Backbone and Phonegap

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, underscore.js, requirejs

I'm creating a phonegap application which involves backbone.js, underscore.js, and require.js I want to ask if i run the optimizer of require.js will it still work with phonegap? How can i use the optimizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this will work. But for android there is a Problem (http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/9c5275bab1cdf9a3) with the define  function in PhoneGap 1.5.0. (1.4.1 Works Fine i use the optimized Version)